# Javascript return function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create some javascript object with few functions, but i get a exception

> undefined is not a function

JS:

```
 var Buses = null;
 $(function () {
        Buses = function() {
            return {
                Test: function () {
                    console.log('test public function');
                }
            }
        }
 });
```

HTMl:

```
<button onclick="Buses.Test()">test</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/buses.js" ></script>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Buses variable is a function that returns a function so in the HTML it must be called like this

```
<button onclick="Buses().Test()">test</button>
```

While you are using jQuery, a better solution would be to give the button an and then assign the click handler right in the javascript:

```
var Buses = null;
$(function () {
    Buses = function() {
        return {
            Test: function () {
                alert('test public function');
            }
        }
    }

    $("#button").click(function() {Buses().Test()});
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fe5hxo60/

Comment: he's be better yet creating a single instance of `Buses` and referring to that in the click handler.